# Issue with using 100vh when adjacent <div> has table at bottom

Tags: html, css

On my website I have 3 columns basically, left, right and middle. Left and right just have a background whilst the middle is where all the data/info etc are.

Now, in my css I have put height: 100vh for my left/right divs so they both span the page. However, I from what I can see, if I have a table at the bottom of the middle div which increases the default page height, the 100vh does not extend accordingly. Quick example using jsfiddle shown below, any help would be much appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/Alija/464u6jct/

```
<div id="MainLeft"  >   </div>

<div id="MainCenter">



<br>
<h5> Blash </h5> <br>
<h5> Blash </h5> <br>
<h5> Blash </h5> <br>
<h5> Blash </h5> <br>
<h5> Blash </h5> <br>
<h5> Blash </h5> <br>
<h5> Blash </h5> <br>
<h5> Blash </h5> <br>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="TrustTable" align="center">

        <th> A </th>                    <th> Role </th>
            <tr> <td> A </td>           <td> A </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Dr. Mohammed Akram Hossain </td>  <td> Member </td></tr>
            <tr> <td> A </td>           <td> A </td></tr>
            <tr> <td> A </td>                   <td> Member </td></tr>
            <tr> <td> Am </td>              <td> Member </td></tr>
            <tr> <td> A </td>   <td> Member </td></tr>
            <tr> <td> An </td>              <td> Member </td></tr>
        </table> <br><br>

    </div>


<div id="MainRight" >   </div>
```

CSS code:

```
  #MainLeft{

    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    height:100vh;

}


#MainCenter{

    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100vh;
    display: table;
}


#MainRight{

    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    height: 100vh;

}




#TrustTable {

    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: It puts the message: `Blocked content

We're sorry, but we've decided to prevent this content from rendering`

Comment: jsfiddle link is 404

Comment: `vh` is short for "viewport height", not "page height". Does that answer your question?

Comment: overflow ? https://jsfiddle.net/1kw8uet9/1/